# Filter drop areas in jQuery drag and drop

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a list of draggable elements (`.item`) and drop areas (`.droparea`).

```
<div class="sortable">
    <div class="droparea" id="div0">Drop area 0</div>
    <div class="item" id="item1">Item 1</div>
    <div class="droparea" id="div1">Drop area 1</div>
    <div class="item" id="item2">Item 2</div>
    <div class="droparea" id="div2">Drop area 2</div>
    <div class="item" id="item3">Item 3</div>
    <div class="droparea" id="div3">Drop area 3</div>
</div>
```

My goal is to allow an element to be dropped in drop areas, excluding its surrounding areas (for example, `#item1` can be dropped in `#div2` and `#div3` but not in `#div0` and `#div1`).

I've tried to reject drops with the [draggable revert](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-revert) option. Everytime a  drop occurs, I compare the current dropping area with the drop areas surrounding the dragged element (stored when dragging begins). If a match occurs, the drop is rejected, else it's accepted.

```
revert: function(valid)
{
    if(valid) 
    {
        // compare dropping area with forbidden areas
        if(dropped==prevDrop || dropped==nextDrop)
        {
            console.log('invalid drop');
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('valid drop ' + dropped.attr('id'));
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8ypo1ykr/5/)

Unfortunately, it doesn't work: drops are always accepted. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done a great work and a minor change is required for actually making this code work ,

Just change the comparison method in `revert` to ,

```
if(dropped.prop("id")==prevDrop.prop("id") || dropped.prop("id")==nextDrop.prop("id"))
```

You were using object comparison here, But result of these values when i drop *Item1* to *div0* ,

```
console.log(dropped);
console.log(prevDrop);
console.log(nextDrop);
```

Looks ,

[image]

It seems using `dropped = $(this);` in `droppable` results adding `context: div#div0.droparea.ui-droppable` which differs from that of `draggable`. Hence causing the problem in comparison.

#### Here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ypo1ykr/6/).

Comment: Interesting analysis. Thanks for the solution.